# separate year from date object in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have an issue regarding separate `year` from date object. I just came to know whenever I pass the String to the DATE object then my years is incremented by 1 or 2 .
for example.

```
var licenceStartDateConv = new Date(licenceStartDate);
var licenceStartDateYear = licenceStartDateConv.getUTCFullYear();
```

when i pass the licenceStartDate = "`13/08/2011`" then the function returns me **licenceStartDateYear** = `Sun Jan 8 00:00:00 UTC+0500 2012` instead of `2011`. why is it so?

can someone please sort out this issue ? I shall be very grateful to you people.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the function has already deprecated, I have searched alot then I came to the conclusion to ask the question. and you gave the -negative point.

Comment: There is a date format issue. Monrths are exceeding 12 thats why year is coming 1 added. Try to correct your date format.

Comment: i could not because the date format used is UK is dd/mm/yyyy where as in US its mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: The supply your date as 08/13/2011. Then try it.

Comment: When I use the Data function in javascript, I prefer using a timestamp so there's no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a "xx/yy/zzzz" format to supply a date string to the Date constructor, it will be parsed as "mm/dd/yyyy", as Ankit pointed out in the original question. You will have to parse the date string to pull the Day, Month and Year out and create a Date object using these.

For example:

```
// Parse the date using a regular expression.
var dateFields = /(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})/.exec("13/08/2011");
licenceStartDateConv = new Date(dateFields[3], dateFields[2]-1, dateFields[1]); // -1 on month to account for offset.
```